# Nginx rules for http and https routes

Tags: php, nginx, ssl

I use arch Linux and trying to use secure routes for a laravel(php framework) based blog. I am trying to get both `"HTTP"` and `"HTTPS"` routes for logged in areas work with nginx with Virtual Hosts server blocks. With the below config,I added both http and ssl in the same config file  now all the routes are accepted as HTTPS. How can I seperate them for certain routes?

```
server {

                listen          80;

                server_name     remaker.dev;

                access_log      /var/log/nginx/sirtcantalilar.dev/access.log;
                error_log       /var/log/nginx/sirtcantalilar.dev/error.log;
                #rewrite_log     on;

                root            /home/ytsejam/public_html/remaker/public;
                index           index.php;
                # Added cache headers for images, quick fix for cloudfront.

                location ~* \.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif)$ {

                        expires 30d;
                        log_not_found off;

                }

                # Only 3 hours on CSS/JS to allow me to roll out fixes during
                # early weeks.

                location ~* \.(js|css|ico)$ {

                        expires 3h;
                        log_not_found off;

                }

                # Heres my redirect, try normal URI and then our Laravel urls.

                location / {

                        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;

                        # A bunch of perm page redirects from my old
                        # site structure for SEO purposes. Not interesting.



                }

                # Look below for this. I decided it was common to Laravel
                # sites so put it in an extra template.

                  # Rewrite for content.

    if (!-d $request_filename) {

            rewrite ^/(.+)/$ /$1 permanent;

    }


    location ~* \.php$ {

            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;

            fastcgi_index  index.php;
 fastcgi_intercept_errors        off;
            fastcgi_ignore_client_abort     off;
            fastcgi_connect_timeout 60;
            fastcgi_send_timeout 180;
            fastcgi_pass                    unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;

            # Typical vars in here, nothing interesting.

            include                         /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param                   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
}


 server {

            listen          443 ssl;

            server_name     remaker.dev;

            access_log      /var/log/nginx/sirtcantalilar.dev/access.log;
            error_log       /var/log/nginx/sirtcantalilar.dev/error.log;
                #rewrite_log     on;

            root            /home/ytsejam/public_html/remaker/public;
            index           index.php;
            ssl on;
            ssl_certificate      /etc/nginx/ssl/remaker.dev/server.crt;
            ssl_certificate_key  /etc/nginx/ssl/remaker.dev/server.key;
            ssl_protocols        SSLv3 TLSv1;
            ssl_ciphers          HIGH:!ADH:!MD5;

            # Added cache headers for images, quick fix for cloudfront.

            location ~* \.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif)$ {

                    expires 30d;
                    log_not_found off;

            }

            # Only 3 hours on CSS/JS to allow me to roll out fixes during
            # early weeks.

            location ~* \.(js|css|ico)$ {

                    expires 3h;
                    log_not_found off;

            }

            # Heres my redirect, try normal URI and then our Laravel urls.

            location / {

                    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;

                    # A bunch of perm page redirects from my old
                    # site structure for SEO purposes. Not interesting.

                    #include /etc/nginx/templates/redirects;

            }
 # Look below for this. I decided it was common to Laravel
            # sites so put it in an extra template.


            location ~* \.php$ {

            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;

            fastcgi_index  index.php;

            fastcgi_intercept_errors        off;
            fastcgi_ignore_client_abort     off;
            fastcgi_connect_timeout 60;
            fastcgi_send_timeout 180;
            fastcgi_pass                    unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;

            # Typical vars in here, nothing interesting.

            include                         /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param                   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

        }
```

Thanks for helps.

Comment: What do you mean by "separating" them?

Comment: I did success this they work. I thought they would go on seperate folders. but they should be on the same page for Virtual Hosts.